# Laravel : Form Multiple Values

Tags: php, forms, laravel-4

I don't understand how to create a Form with multiple select values in Laravel.

```
<?php $genre = array(
'Action' => 'Action',
'Biography' => 'Biography',
'Drama' => 'Drama',
'Crime' => 'Crime'
);
?>

{{ Form::label('genre', trans('main.genre')) }}
{{ Form::select('genre', $genre, array('Action'), array('multiple' => true, 'class' =>'form-control')); }}
```

From here if I select Action and Biography, only the last value (biography) gets saved into the "Genre" Field

If I change genre to genre[]

```
<?php $genre = array(
'Action' => 'Action',
'Biography' => 'Biography',
'Drama' => 'Drama',
'Crime' => 'Crime'
);
?>

{{ Form::label('genre', trans('main.genre')) }}
{{ Form::select('genre[]', $genre, array('Action'), array('multiple' => true, 'class' => 'form-control')); }}
```

I receive the error
Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are declaring your `multiple` correctly.

first off, completely forget the 2nd piece of code you posted.  The first parameter of the `Form::select` is the name and this is a string.  By putting `[]` it's making it an array, so that's a non-starter.

Your field call should be:

```
{{ Form::select('genre', $genre, array('Action'), array('multiple', 'class' =>'form-control')); }}
```

Comment: Hi, it is still storing only the last value eg if I select Action and Biography, only the last value (biography) gets saved into the "Genre" Field

Comment: Can you show the code you use to store the form input?